# Zend Studio Browser Toolbars alternative for PhpStorm 3?

Tags: php, zend-studio, phpstorm, zend-debugger

I've been working with [Zend Studio](http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/) now for a long time, and there is a super useful resource called **Studio Browser Toolbar**, which is basically a Firefox Toolbar that allows me start debugging a web page from the browser directly into Zend Studio.

Now I started working with [PhpStorm 3](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/), and I've been trying to find an alternative for that Zend Studio feature.

I've already made the basic debug configuration for PhpStorm to debug with Zend Debugger, from my Zend Server installation. Now I need some sort of feature that allows me to debug a specific web page from the browser.

So, is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it's working out of the box with the original toolbar, if you're using the ZendDebugger.

Here are [instructions](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/WI/Configure+Zend+Debugger+Toolbar+for+Firefox+to+work+with+PhpStorm)

Answer (score 4):

Please [refer to the documentation](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2011/02/zero-configuration-debugging-with-xdebug-and-phpstorm-2-0/), it describes how you can create [bookmarklets](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/) (that can be placed in your browser bookmarks bar and trigger debug in PhpStorm).